# Write custom attribute on final_price.phtml

Tags: php, price, magento2.1.6

I would like to get a custom attribute "bum" (base unit of measure) on the page "final_price.phtml".
Do you know if it's possible to add a custom attribute after the price to something like this:

- before : $ 2.35
- after : $ 2.35 per RL

final_price.phtml:
[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

Create plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox">
    <plugin name="sr_quantity_type_product_render_amount" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Pricing\Render\PriceBox" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/Pricing/Render/PriceBox.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\AmountInterface;

class PriceBox
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * PriceBox constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function aroundRenderAmount(
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        AmountInterface $amount,
        array $arguments = []
    ) {
        $html = $proceed($amount, $arguments);
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($subject->getSaleableItem()->getId());
        $bum = $product->getBum() ? $product->getAttributeText('bum') : '';
        if ($bum) {
            $html .= '<div>' . __('per') . ' ' .$bum . '</div>';;
        }

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the repply. I don't have the folder 'Module' in 'Vendor'. I have to create it?

Comment: Yes, it's your custom module.

Comment: Ok, can you say me where I have to put the first part (<type ... </type>) ?

Comment: Inside di.xml, read more http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: I put the di.xml file here: /vendor/module/plugin/pricing/etc/di.xml, is it correct?

Comment: Do you know if I have to run a command line to upgrade magento or something like this after? Thanks

Comment: You should try create a M2 module then add above answer.

Comment: Do you know if I can modify the existing module instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Don't do this .